# How to return the key that I wrote if the key was not found

Tags: java, hashmap

Let's say we have a `HashMap` named `hsm`, and I want the value of `hsm.get(invalidKey)`.

Because the `invalidKey` has no mapping it will return for me a `null` value, but I want it to return for me the `invalidKey`.

I already know of a method where we check first if `hsm.containsKey(invalidKey)` to make sure it's valid and not overwriting a  value in the array, but ***is there another method?***

Comment: You say you want `hsm.get(invalidKey)` to return the invalid key, but how would you tell the difference between that and a valid item in the hash map where the key and value are the same?

Comment: I didn't thought about that, but in my case it wouldn't be useful because I'm trying to map some texts to emotes (<3 -> heart , etc...). I will take my String = text and say : String [] txt = text.split(" "), then I will traverse the array index by index and for each I will replace it with hsm.getOrDefault(txt[i],txt[i]). Either way thank you for shedding the light about this concept

Comment: `hsm.get(..)` would return the **value**, not the **key**, so unless key and value are the same type, this is a rather odd requirement which cannot be realised in a type-safe way.

Answer (score 1):

I should have used:

`hsm.getOrDefault(invalidKey, invalidKey);`

It searches the map using the first argument as a key. If no result is found then the second argument is returned, which in this case is the same as the key.

Comment: `hsm.getOrDefault(..)` would return the **value**, not the **key**, so unless key and value are the same type, this is a rather odd requirement which cannot be realised in a type-safe way.